Avoid repetition of strings in SQL query
I have a SQL query where the list of strings is repeated twice: ('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bletch'). What is the most maintainable method to avoid such repetition and make this code more DRY?
I am not optimizing query performance, only maintainability.
select
    *
from
    gizmo_details
where
    _gizmo_name in ('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bletch')
    or gizmo_id in
    (select id from gizmos where
        gizmo_name in ('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bletch'));


You could move them into a CTE - but you'd need to change your query to use INNER JOIN with the CTE instead of WHERE IN)

Your gizmo_details._gizmo_name column is a denormalization. What happens if a gizmos.gizmo_name differs from a dependent gizmo_details._gizmo_name?

Seems to me this should be solved with a Foreign Key on gizmo_details._gizmo_name <--> gizmos.gizmo_name.

@AdrianKlaver There's also gizmo_details.gizmo_id

Either way there seems to be after the fact referential integrity going on presently.

You can move that to an array in a subquery.
select * from gizmo_details, (select array['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bletch']::text[])_(string_arr) where _gizmo_name=any(string_arr) or gizmo_id in(select id from gizmos where gizmo_name=any(string_arr));: demo

@Dai These tables are not normalized yet. They are now in an intermediate state, and are currently being refactored to be normalized, along the lines you mentioned. And gizmo_details._gizmo_name will then be dropped.

@AdrianKlaver Please see the comment above. The tables are being refactored currently. My question is about what is the best solution in the meantime, to avoid duplicating the strings.

Against SQL - It should be read by everyone.

@AlexanderPetrov Care to elaborate?

@Zegarek - It's hard to avoid repetition in ANSI SQL. Your answer is good. PostgreSQL allow to do this simply by having arrays. But in many other RDBMS it will not work so elegantly.

Is the different column name _gizmo_name vs.gizmo_name a typo or intended?

@ErwinBrandstetter The column name _gizmo_name is named with an underscore prefix because it is now deprecated and it will go away in one of the next refactorings. It used to be called gizmo_name, without the underscore, previously.

DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself.
Repeated rows?
Multiple rows in gizmo_details can match the same input string. Such duplicates are preserved.
But the same row in gizmo_details can match multiple input strings (if there can be duplicate input), or the same gizmo_details.gizmo_id can qualify multiple times. Such duplicates are removed.
This may or may not be an issue. It's just something that tends to get overlooked. Several of the solutions posted so far are not true to your original in this respect.
If there can be dupes in any of the three sets (tables, input), you might want to spell out how to deal with dupes. There are fitting query styles for any possible specification.
You did not ask for optimizing query performance (which may be possible on top of anything else here), but correctness always comes first.
Repetition within a single query
A CTE is one way to keep a single query DRY:
WITH input(gizmo_name) AS (
   SELECT unnest('{foo, bar, baz, bletch}'::text[])  -- your input as array
   )
SELECT *
FROM   gizmo_details
WHERE  _gizmo_name = ANY (TABLE input)
OR     gizmo_id IN (SELECT g.id FROM gizmos g JOIN input USING (gizmo_name));

Much of this comes down to the question of defining constants in SQL. See:

Is there a way to define a named constant in a PostgreSQL query?

Repetition within the same session
To repeat this query over and over, prepared statements are one way to keep it  DRY:
PREPARE qr1 (text[]) AS
SELECT *
FROM   gizmo_details gd
WHERE  gd._gizmo_name = ANY ($1)
OR     gd.gizmo_id IN (SELECT g.id FROM gizmos g WHERE g.gizmo_name = ANY ($1));

Call:
EXECUTE qr1('{foo, bar, baz, bletch}'::text[]);  -- array input

This (also) prevents repeating the input inside the query.
Prepared statements are built into many client libraries as standard feature.
Repetition across sessions
A server-side function keeps that "DRY". A VARIADIC input parameter is just an optional added feature. See:

Pass multiple values in single parameter

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_my_func(VARIADIC _gizmo_names text[])
  RETURNS SETOF gizmo_details
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT *
FROM   gizmo_details gd
WHERE  gd._gizmo_name = ANY (_gizmo_names)
OR     gd.gizmo_id IN (SELECT g.id FROM gizmos g WHERE g.gizmo_name = ANY (_gizmo_names));
$func$

Call:
SELECT * FROM f_my_func('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bletch');  -- list input

Or:
SELECT * FROM f_my_func(VARIADIC '{foo, bar, baz, bletch}');  -- back to array input

A lot more versatile than prepared statements, plus it can be nested in outer queries (as opposed to a prepared statement).
Aside: using _ as prefix for variables and/or parameters but never for column names is a common naming convention. Optional, but I stick to it.

Array literal in a single-row subquery: demo at db<>fiddle
select * from gizmo_details, 
(select array['foo','bar','baz','bletch'])_(my_string_arr)
where _gizmo_name=any(my_string_arr) 
  or gizmo_id in(select id from gizmos 
                 where gizmo_name=any(my_string_arr));

It can be defined earlier in a Common Table Expression but the CTE would still have to be mentioned again in the FROM list, so you might just as well define it right in that FROM list.
Single-row table:
create table _(my_string_arr)as values('{foo,bar,baz,bletch}'::text[]);

select * from gizmo_details, _
where _gizmo_name=any(my_string_arr) 
  or gizmo_id in(select id from gizmos 
                 where gizmo_name=any(my_string_arr));

Inlineable constant-returning function:
create function _()returns text[] return '{foo,bar,baz,bletch}'::text[];

select * from gizmo_details 
where _gizmo_name=any(_() ) 
  or gizmo_id in(select id from gizmos 
                 where gizmo_name=any(_() ));

Explain analyze shows that all calls to this function get replaced by the constant.
Custom session-wide variable:
set my.var='{foo,bar,baz,bletch}';

select * from gizmo_details 
where _gizmo_name=any(current_setting('my.var')::text[]) 
  or gizmo_id in(select id from gizmos 
                 where gizmo_name=any(current_setting('my.var')::text[]));

Psql also lets you \set it as its own, client-side variable:
\set string_arr $$'{foo,bar,baz,bletch}'$$

select * from gizmo_details
where _gizmo_name=any(:string_arr)
  or gizmo_id in(select id from gizmos 
                 where gizmo_name=any(:string_arr));

As mentioned by @Erwin Brandstetter, one advantage of defining the function or saving the constant to a table is that you do it once, centrally, after which those can be shared and re-used by different clients in separate sessions. A CTE or subquery has to come inside the statement body every time, and session/client variables can't be shared at all.

Using a CTE:
WITH knownGizmos AS (
    SELECT name
    FROM
    (
        VALUES
            ( 'foo' ), ( 'bar' ), ( 'baz' ), ( 'bletch' )
    ) gn ( name )
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    gizmo_details AS gd
    INNER JOIN gizmos AS g ON g.id = gd.gizmo_id

    INNER JOIN knownGizmos ON g.gizmo_name = knownGizmos.name

Unfortunately ISO SQL's VALUES() table-constructor is painfully verbose compared to a Postgres array literal.

An alternative to using VALUES() is a good ol' fashioned UNION:
WITH knownGizmos AS (
    SELECT 'foo'    AS name UNION
    SELECT 'bar'    AS name UNION
    SELECT 'baz'    AS name UNION
    SELECT 'bletch' AS name
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    gizmo_details AS gd
    INNER JOIN gizmos AS g ON g.id = gd.gizmo_id

    INNER JOIN knownGizmos ON g.gizmo_name = knownGizmos.name


With a CTE it would look like this
with t as (
  select array['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bletch'] arr)
select gd.* from gizmo_details gd, t
where _gizmo_name = any (t.arr)
or gizmo_id 
in (select id from gizmos where gizmo_name = any(t.arr));


You're performing the same comparison on two columns. A generic solution to avoid repetition is to place the values from each column as rows of a faux column, and perform the comparison on that column. This approach creates duplicate matches so additional work is needed.

In your example, place the gizmo names from master and detail table into a single column and use the in operator on that column. This could create two rows per gizmo so suppress them using semi join:
select *
from gizmo_details
where exists (
    select *
    from gizmos, lateral (values
        (gizmo_details._gizmo_name),
        (gizmos.gizmo_name)
    ) as x(name)
    where gizmo_details.gizmo_id = gizmos.id
    and x.name in ('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bletch')
)

Or distinct on:
select distinct on (gizmo_details.id) gizmo_details.*
from gizmos
join gizmo_details on gizmos.id = gizmo_details.gizmo_id, lateral (values
    (gizmo_details._gizmo_name),
    (gizmos.gizmo_name)
) as x(name)
where x.name in ('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bletch')


Maintaining a list of strings across two SQL queries can be interpreted in a few different ways. If you mean to create a list from one query and use it in another, or to compare lists from two queries, here are different approaches for common SQL databases:
1.  Using Temporary Tables:You can store the results of the first query into a temporary table and then use it in the second query.-- First query, store results in a temporary table
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_list (value VARCHAR(255));
    INSERT INTO temp_list (value)
    SELECT stringValue FROM your_table WHERE some_condition;
    -- Second query, use results from the temporary table
    SELECT *
    FROM another_table
    WHERE another_column IN (SELECT value FROM temp_list);
    -- Optionally, drop the temporary table if it's no longer needed
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp_list;

2.  Using Subqueries:You can use a subquery directly within the IN clause of your second query.SELECT *
    FROM another_table
    WHERE another_column IN (
        SELECT stringValue
        FROM your_table
        WHERE some_condition
    );
3.  Using Common Table Expressions (CTEs):With Common Table Expressions, you can name a subquery and reference it in the main query.WITH list AS (
        SELECT stringValue
        FROM your_table
        WHERE some_condition
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM another_table
    WHERE another_column IN (SELECT stringValue FROM list);

4.  Using Joins:If you want to join the results of two queries based on strings, you can join tables on the string columns.SELECT a.*
    FROM another_table a
    JOIN your_table b ON a.another_column = b.stringValue
    WHERE b.some_condition;

5.  Storing List in Application Memory:If the lists are not too large, you can store the list of strings from the first query in your application's memory and use it to construct the second query.In pseudocode:list = executeQuery("SELECT stringValue FROM your_table WHERE some_condition")
    executeQuery("SELECT * FROM another_table WHERE another_column IN (" + list.join(", ") + ")")Remember to properly parameterize your queries to prevent SQL injection when using this method.

6.  Using Variables:In some databases like MySQL, you can store results in variables and use them in subsequent queries within the same session.SET @list := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(stringValue SEPARATOR ',') FROM your_table WHERE some_condition);
    SET @query := CONCAT('SELECT * FROM another_table WHERE another_column IN (', @list, ')');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

The appropriate approach depends on the capabilities of your SQL database and the specifics of your use case, such as the size of the data, performance considerations, and whether you need to carry out the operation within a single transaction or session.

Sorry, I need to clarify several items. I am using PostgreSQL. I am also using a single query, as shown in my question, not multiple queries. Could you please clarify your answer, using the specific example from my question? TYIA!

the above lists possible ways. postgresql follows ANSI standards and it should allow all the above syntax. IMO using CTE will be the cleanest approach i.e. #3 above.

WITH string_list AS (
    SELECT 'foo' AS value UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bar' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'baz' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bletch'
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    gizmo_details
WHERE
    _gizmo_name IN (SELECT value FROM string_list)
    OR gizmo_id IN (
        SELECT id FROM gizmos
        WHERE gizmo_name IN (SELECT value FROM string_list)
    );

